# Determining age of a file in Java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to determine how long a file has been on an NTFS file system.

I can read the file creation time, and the system time in millis, but the two do not add up. They are off by a number of years. The NTFS Epoc is 1 JAN 1601 at 0000 hrs UTC, whereas the Java Epoc is 1 JAN 1970. Also, NTFS time is given in 100's of nanoseconds.

Taking all this into account, it still doesn't add up. Where am I going wrong?

```
public static final double secondsPerJulianYear = 316880878;
public static final double minutesPerJulianYear = 5281347.966666667;
public static final double secondsPerMinute = 60.0;
public static final double millisPerSecond = 1000.0;
public static final double yearsJavaTimeAhead = 369.0;

public static long ntfsFileCreationTime(final File file) {
    FileTime fileCreationTime = null;
    try {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(file.toURI());
        if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
            BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);             
            fileCreationTime = attributes.creationTime();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getJavaMillisFromNtfsTime(fileCreationTime.toMillis());
}

public static long getJavaMillisFromNtfsTime(final long ntfsTime) {
    double ntfsNanos = ntfsTime * 100; // An NTFS time unit is equal to 100 nanoseconds 
    double ntfsMillis = (ntfsNanos / 10E6); // There are 10e6 nanoseconds in a millisecond
    double millisJavaEpocAhead = yearsJavaTimeAhead * minutesPerJulianYear * secondsPerMinute * millisPerSecond;
    return (long) (ntfsMillis - millisJavaEpocAhead);
}

According to Windows 7, the creation date is: 1/6/2016
This is the console output of one of the files: 

System.currentTimeMillis(): 1454896412295
fileCreationTime(fileName): -116929029460761
file age: 118383925873056
```

Comment: Are sure the creationTime() is not in millis since Epoch as well?

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc for [FileTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html)

> public static FileTime fromMillis(long value)
>
> Returns
>
> a FileTime representing the given value in milliseconds.
>
> Parameters:
>
> value - the
> value, in milliseconds, since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z); can be
> negative Returns: a FileTime representing the given value

Note, that epoch is the same, and the time is in millis.

So your method should be

```
public static long getJavaMillisFromNtfsTime(final long ntfsTime) {
     return ntfsTime;
}
```

Note: when you get an exception, you can't continue and pretend it didn't happen. In your case you will just get a NullPointerException.  I suggest you either don't catch an IOException or return a clearly invalid value like Long.MIN_VALUE